# Good solar absorptivity and infrared emissivity values for non-anodized machined aluminum

Tags: spacecraft, radiation, thermal

Existing sources that I'm looking at show a wide range of possible absorptivity/emissivity values for aluminum:

http://www.solarmirror.com/fom/fom-serve/cache/43.html

https://www.thermoworks.com/emissivity-table/

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/radiation-surface-absorptivity-d_1805.html

Any inputs on good values to use for machine-finish non-anodized aluminum in a thermal desktop simulation?  Currently using solar absorptivity of 0.2 and an IR emissivity of 0.4 with an a/e ratio of 0.5.  This is just kind of middle ground in the ranges of values I'm seeing in the aforementioned sources.

recommendation much appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest that you bring some of the data from the references into the text of the question?  This a) prevents link rot from causing loss of the important bits and b) will probably encourage more folks to read and consider answering the question.

Comment: I would look at what I was analyzing or using and run my calcs at the ranges of the published numbers to see how influential those radiation numbers were in getting to the goal.  Also run calcs using the average.  Should get an idea of how imporatant the numbers are.  If this is an analyis of something to be built,  I don't think the costs of running a test would be that significant.  If you're in an academic environment, you could probably generate your own test.

Answer (score 1):

Intended as “comment”, not “answer”:

You may be headed down the rabbit hole looking for accurate absorptivity/emissivity data for your machined aluminum. Published numbers vary widely, as you have found out. Part of the problem is the propensity of aluminum (E=0.03) to oxidize. So a polished aluminum surface rapidly turns into aluminum oxide (E=0.75) in the presence of oxygen.

Emissivity depends partially on the relationship of surface geometry to wavelength. Therefore the emissivity changes with surface treatment (polishing, oxidation, solar radiation) as well as wavelength (emissivity falls with increasing wavelength).

[image]

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0017931017325802

If your simulation is for a spacecraft, you will need to allow for oxidation between manufacturing and launch. It may be more practical to surface coat the aluminum so you are dealing with a known E.